# Saving source string of image in richtextbox after moving or pasting from clipboard

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, clipboard, imagesource

I'm working on richtextbox, which can handle images. I'm saving xaml content of richtextbox to database as string. Images are saved in the folder tree.  And I have one problem:

When I insert image to richtextbox (in InlineUIContainer) all is working, saving and loading makes no problem. But when I drag image or cut and paste image again, source path of image is changed:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage BaseUri="pack://payload:,,wpf1,/Xaml/Document.xaml" 
                     UriSource="./Image1.jpeg" CacheOption="OnLoad" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

original source was:

```
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/path_to_image/some_image.jpg" />
```

And therefore, when I save xaml again (still everything ok), I can't load images again, because in the xaml there are wrong paths to them (not ok :-)).

I searched for it, but I haven't found any solution. Could You help me please?

Comment: Is path_to always the same folder as your EXE resides in?

Comment: It is path to image in folder somewhere in subtree of directory, where is stored EXE file.

Comment: I found another way, I am saving it to the XAML package, Images are copied into it and everything worcs perfect

Comment: You should add this as an answer, and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way, I am saving it to the XAML package, Images are copied into it and everything works perfect.