# Keep source of image in RichTextBox after pasting or moving the image

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm using a RichTextBox thant can contains images. I import them with an `OpenFileDialog` and put then into an `InlineUIContainer`.

It is displayed and the xaml code is as follows.

```
<Paragraph>
    <Image Source="file://C:/Path/Test.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Height="100" />
</Paragraph>
```

I can save my xaml document in the database, close it and open it again without any problems, the image will still be displayed.

But if I ever move the image from within the document oc copy and paste it, my xaml code becomes as follow :

```
<BlockUIContainer>
    <Image Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Height="100">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage BaseUri="pack://payload:,,wpf3,/Xaml/Document.xaml" UriSource="./Image1.png" CacheOption="OnLoad" />
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</BlockUIContainer>
```

It is now contained within a BlockUIContainer, which I don't want for display purposes, but it's not my bigger problem, because I lost the ImageSource, thus not able to display them again.

Do you have any  solutions to prevent this behavior ?

I tried to intercept the Copy and Paste event with `DataObject.AddCopyingHandler` et `DataObject.AddPastingHandler`, but couldn't manage to get the desired result.

I also found this question [Saving source string of image in richtextbox after moving or pasting from clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515636/saving-source-string-of-image-in-richtextbox-after-moving-or-pasting-from-clipbo) with a similar problem but I don't understand what is meant by "saving it to the XAML Package".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the [`DataFormats.XamlPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataformats.xamlpackage?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-dataformats-xamlpackage)

> Specifies the Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) package
> data format.

In other words, this format gives possibility to save document as a packed `xaml`. Actually, this is archived document: binary file.

Therefore, instead of saving to a file you can get bytes array and save in to the database as binary data (`varbinary`) and when this is necessary load it to the `RichTextBox` back.

---

Below you can find some example that demonstrate how you can use this format to save/load a document from the `RichTextBox` to save and restore documents containing images.

The `MainWindow.xaml`:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="550" 
        x:Name="mainWindow" Topmost="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="rtb" AllowDrop="True" Padding="2" FontSize="18"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >         
        </RichTextBox>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="3">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Save" Margin="2" Padding="3">Save</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Click="Button_Load" Margin="2" Padding="3">Load</Button>
        </Grid>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfApp11
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { rtb.SaveRtf(); }

        private void Button_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { rtb.LoadRtf(); }
    }

    public static class RichTextBoxExt
    {
        public static void SaveRtf(this RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog
            {
                DefaultExt = ".xpack",
                Filter = "XamlPackage Files (*.xpack)|*.xpack|All Files|*.*"
            };

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var range = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        range.Save(ms, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
                        using (var file = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            ms.WriteTo(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void LoadRtf(this RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
            {
                DefaultExt = ".xpack",
                Filter = "XamlPackage Files (*.xpack)|*.xpack|All Files|*.*"
            };

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                var range = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
                using (var stream = new StreamReader(dlg.FileName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        range.Load(stream.BaseStream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is working well, and seems better for the storage aspect so I'm gonna adapt my program to work with this solution.
Thanks a lot for your time and example !

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that is closer to my original question, if someone ever needs it.

I add the Handlers for Copy and Paste (alors works when you move the Image into the RichTextBox)

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="Rtb" Loaded="Rtb_Loaded"/>
```

```
private void Rtb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(Rtb, OnCopy);
    DataObject.AddPastingHandler(Rtb, OnPaste);
}
```

When the user copies, we read all the blocks of the document and store all the images within the selection. [FindImages code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908323/18486478)

```
private readonly List<Image> _copiedImages = new List<Image>();

private void OnCopy(object sender, DataObjectCopyingEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    _copiedImages.Clear();
    TextPointer lineStart = rtb.Selection.Start.GetLineStartPosition(i);

    while (lineStart != null)
    {
        Block actualBlock = lineStart.Paragraph;
        List<Image> images = FindImages(actualBlock).ToList();
        if (images != null)
        {
            foreach (Image img in images)
            {
                _copiedImages.Add(img);
            }
        }

        lineStart = lineStart.Paragraph == rtb.Selection.End.Paragraph ? 
            null : rtb.Selection.Start.GetLineStartPosition(i++);        
    }
}
```

The OnPaste event is triggered when the user paste its clipboard, but the content is not in the RichTextBox yet. I haven't found any way to change the content to keep track of the source, but here is the trick that helped me found the solution :

```
private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    rtb.TextChanged += OnPastedExecuted;
}
```

Indeed, now you have an event after the content has been pasted. I feel so dumb to miss this for so long, but now I can easily change the content just after it has been pasted.

```
private void OnPastedExecuted(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Image> documentImages = FindImages(rtb.Document).ToList();
    int pos = 0;

    foreach (Image img in documentImages)
    {
        // The copied Images dont have name
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(img.Name))
        {
            // Generate a random name to prevent any issue in Xaml
            string name = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();
            img.Name = name.Substring(0, name.LastIndexOf("."));
            img.Source = _copiedImages[pos].Source;
            pos++;
        }
    }
    rtb.TextChanged -= OnPastedExecuted;
}
```

And there it is ! I can easily move my images in the document, copy many and keep the source.

Let me know if you find any problem in the code or see any improvement / optimization !